# apache, phusion passenger, and memory usage

Tags: ruby, apache, ubuntu, passenger, ram

I read this article somewhere:

"With a plain Apache server, it doesn’t matter much if you run many child processes—the processes are about 1 MB each (most of it shared), so they don’t eat a lot of RAM. The situation is different with mod_perl, where the processes can easily grow to 10 MB and more. For example, if you have MaxClients set to 50, the memory usage becomes 50 × 10 MB = 500 MB.Do you have 500 MB of RAM dedicated to the mod_perl server?"

I'm not using mod_perl on my server. I am using phusion passenger and ruby on rails with apache2. I am using prefork MPM and the MaxClients is set to the default 256. That means I can have 256 processes running concurrently at any given time. The article piqued my interest because I never have 256 apache2 processes running concurrently, usually I only have 80 apache2 processes running at any given time. But sometimes even just 80 bogs down my server to the point where the site just hangs when you try to load it.

When I run the following command, it sometimes shows 80 apache2 processes, for example:

```
ps aux | grep apache2
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      1130  0.0  0.1 149080 10600 ?        Ss   12:36   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2051  0.0  0.3 163608 23592 ?        S    16:46   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2506  0.0  0.1 149376  7952 ?        S    16:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5149  0.0  0.1 149416  7980 ?        S    16:49   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  5175  0.0  0.1 149368  7876 ?        S    16:49   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 10212  0.0  0.1 149368  7848 ?        S    16:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 19114  0.0  0.1 149368  7904 ?        S    17:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 19138  0.0  0.1 150768 11856 ?        S    17:01   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 20592  0.0  0.1 149428  8092 ?        S    16:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 21336  0.0  0.1 149368  7808 ?        S    17:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 21375  0.0  0.1 149432  7916 ?        S    17:03   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
1000     26458  0.0  0.0   8112   896 pts/6    S+   17:07   0:00 grep apache2
www-data 30848  0.0  0.1 149396  8044 ?        S    16:43   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

But under memory, they range from 0.1 to 0.4, which doesn't seem like a lot of memory. So my question is when you send a request to the site from the browser, in addition to spawning a new apache2 process as a child process to the parent apache2 process, does passenger also create another process, something that could possibly be bogging down memory? When I run the top command, I notice sometimes it shows a ruby process at %100 CPU. I am wondering is that ruby process somehow linked to the apache2 processes via passenger. Something must be causing these processes to grow to big memory consumers, like that article stated. There must be something I am not looking at.

By the way, I have more than 5 gigs of memory on the machine:

```
$ cat meminfo
MemTotal:        6113156 kB
```

Comment: ps -A | grep apache2 had larger result than ps aux | grep apache2, i think that's because the latter just showed active processes, while the former showed running processes - I think apache2 has processes sitting idly waiting to be used - so that a process doesn't need to be spawned the moment it is needed (which would be time consuming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phusion Passenger spawns your Ruby application processes separately. View them with `passenger-memory-stats` or `passenger-status`.

Comment: Ok, so I ran passenger-memory-stats and it did show the same processes as you would get with ps aux, but its much more limited and not useful. It's not useful because it only gives you virtual memory size (which is swap disk + resident memory (pure RAM memory). I want the actual memory this process is using, excluding shared libraries. I usually get that with pmap command, which does virtual mapping to physical mapping, and gives you a sum minus libraries. How can I get that with the aforementioned passenger commands?

Comment: I updated my comment above to be more clear to what I am looking for.

Comment: What do you mean? passenger-memory-stats displays all Phusion Passenger-related processes, that is all web server processes + all Phusion Passenger internal processes + all Ruby processes. It should also tell you the Private Dirty Resident Set Size of each process, which is one of the most accurate measures of memory usage, and excludes shared memory (such as read-only shared library data). But for that latter metric you must run it as root, otherwise it'll just report VMSize. Did you run the tool as root?

Comment: It does not let me run passenger-memory-stats as sudo

Comment: You indicated on the mailing list that with "doesn't work" you mean that you get a 'command not found' error. Read [the Phusion Passenger manual](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_the_path_environment_variable) for the solution. In particular, you will want to read section "About environment variables", subsections "The PATH environment variable", "Adding Phusion Passenger’s administration tools to PATH" and "Environment variables and sudo".

Comment: Can you take a look at my question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/jo-s1W4UiIk I still cannot get this running with sudo

Comment: using rvmsudo (which is what you recommended in google groups) and referencing the path the program is located in in the linux filesystem worked. So if you can update your answer to that, then I can mark it correct